# How to convert openerp 7 module to odoo 8

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

Some useful module in openerp 7, such as "purchase_requisition_double_validation" but when installed there is error messages:

```
File "/opt/odoo/data/addons/purchase_requisition_analytic/analytic.py", line 22, in <module>
from osv import fields, osv
```

ImportError: No module named osv

So, how can I modify this module to make it Odoo 8 compatible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
from osv import fields, osv
```

to:

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
```

That should do it! :]

Answer (score 0):

For importing use following:

`from openerp import models,fields,api`

Also you can refer to this link for how to create modules in odoo

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html

https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/what-blogs-tutorials-forums-exist-about-odoo-68797

Comment: This is true if you want to use the new 8.0 API, but the old 7.0 API also still works. In fact half of Odoo's own modules still run on the old API.

Answer (score -1):

If you are working in ODOO 8.0 stable version then refers the ODOO Addons Modules like **Event** that's more helpful for your  new ODOO 8.0 decorator Module development and implementation.